# Ubuntu - #include <curl/curl.h> no such file or directory

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, curl

I'm developping a C-program using Curl on Ubuntu. I'm using Eclipse Kepler.
I have installed the curl library using

> apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

And I checked if everything is allright usign

> ls -l /usr/include/curl

I got

> total 172
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7065 janv. 31 16:49 curlbuild.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 81593 janv. 31 16:49 curl.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8901 janv. 31 16:49 curlrules.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2741 janv. 31 16:49 curlver.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3472 janv. 31 16:49 easy.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2790 janv. 31 16:49 mprintf.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12981 janv. 31 16:49 multi.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1330 janv. 31 16:49 stdcheaders.h
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 36048 janv. 31 16:49 typecheck-gcc.h

Although my curl.h file is there, Eclipse wrote this message when I tried to build my program :

> fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.

What did I forget to set ? Everything looks good ! :'(
Thanks !

Comment: what command did you run to build? what does your $PATH look like?

Comment: Oh man ! That's it, actually I use a specific environment variables which are located in /opt/toolchains/arm-2011.V2/bin.

Should my curl.h be somewhere here ?

Comment: Just a note of thanks for showing us which package to add for libcurl - "apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C compilers' (preprocessors', actually) standard include file searching paths should include `/usr/include`, therefore if the include file `curl.h`  is located in `/usr/include/curl/` and is included by `#include <curl/curl.h>`, C compilers, such as `gcc`, should be able to find it without any problem.

However, you are using a toolchain under `/opt/toolchains/arm-2011.V2/bin`, I guess it is a cross-compiling toolchain. In this case, you cannot use the curl library, because which is for the host system, which probably is a x86 or x86_64 system.

To use curl library in your ARM project, you need to install the curl library development package for ARM, if that is possible. If the software repositories do not have those packages, then you need to download the source code and cross-compile it for ARM first.

Comment: Hum, actually I am not familiar with this compiler,Gcc,gdb, ... stuff. I work for a school project and I use cross-compilation for arm. The toolchain is located in /opt/toolchains/arm-2011.V2. I added the environment variable PATH = /opt/toolchains/arm-2011.V2/bin. Is there something to do between this and my curl.h file ?

Comment: @user3493179 In this case, you cannot use that curl library you just installed, unless your Linux distribution is for ARM.

Comment: Well, the embedded system I am working on is a system which host a linux distribution on an ARM9. I don't know what is the distribution used. Do I need to know that before trying to compile it with its specific toolchain ?

Is there an other way to send data to a web server without using curl ?

:'(

Comment: @user3493179 You do not need to know which Linux distribution you are using to cross-compile curl library. However, you do need to use your cross-compiling toolchain to build that library for your ARM project. If you have a full-fledged ARM Linux distribution, and you can do all your development work in it, then everything will be much more easier.

Comment: Well, I can't do my development directly on my ARM Linux distribution, I need to work though the CC toolchain. Hum, I need to find an other way if curl doesn't work with it ... damn !

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl /usr/include/curl
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you've got `curl.h` installed to your default location (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). If you don't, you can clone and install from [GitHub](https://github.com/curl/curl).

Once you've cloned it, just use these commands:

```
./buildconf
./configure
make
cd include # ONLY install the include folder (with curl.h, etc)
make install
```

And you should be done. If you need further help, check the `GIT-INFO` file in the base directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this. Find your curl.h file - it shoud be where you installed your curl '...\include\curl\curl.h'
So instead of writing in your code this '#include ', write all path like here '#include '.
It is possible to help you!
Good luck )