# qt c++ error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, curl, libcurl

I downloaded the libcURL source code and imported the headers and source into my .pro file and it seems to find all the libraries except for the main one.

dies on:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

.pro file contains:
(this is the updated version)....................

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = RESTtest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src/CurlMulti.cpp \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src/CurlHeader.cpp \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src/CurlVersion.cpp \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src/CurlEasy.cpp \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src/CurlShare.cpp \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src/CurlMessage.cpp \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src/CurlHttpPost.cpp \


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlEasy.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlInterface.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlMulti.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlPair.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlVersion.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlHttpPost.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlHeader.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlShare.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlMessage.h \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include/CurlError.h \


FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
win32:LIBS += -L"../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl-7.34.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-winidn-static-bin-w64" -lcurl
INCLUDEPATH += "../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curlcpp/src"
INCLUDEPATH += "../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl/include/curl"

OTHER_FILES += \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl-7.34.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-winidn-static-bin-w64/curl.exe \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl-7.34.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-winidn-static-bin-w64/libeay32.dll \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl-7.34.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-winidn-static-bin-w64/libcurl.dll \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl-7.34.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-winidn-static-bin-w64/ssleay32.dll \
    ../../../../../Users/Brad2/Documents/GitHub/curl-7.34.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-winidn-static-bin-w64/mk-ca-bundle.vbs
```

Comment: What is the full path to the curl/curl.h file?

Comment: And why are you importing the source code directly, instead of building the library?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp  is the copy i used and I don't see curl.h.  C:\Users\Brad2\Documents\GitHub\curlcpp  is my path and I am static linking source so that it is fully built into the final build.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834233/ubuntu-include-curl-curl-h-no-such-file-or-directory

This could come from your OS version.

Comment: The link you provided states `An object-oriented C++ **wrapper** for cURL tool` and in the `CMakeLists.txt` file cUrl appears as a dependency. Most likely you first have to install cUrl and then tell CMake where to find it.

Comment: I find the MinGW64 dev download for curl here  http://curl.haxx.se/download.html  But is only provides a binary and some dlls. On a whim I imported them as 'other files', but the same error exist. I have never tried to suck a binary up into c++. No clue  (Linux guy, first win32 project)

Comment: What compiler are you using? And, following the instructions in the link you provided, I suppose you want the "Standalone" version of curlcpp. If you build `curlcpp` with the gui of CMake, when you "Configure" the project, it will most likely complain about `cURL`. Then you can specify the path to the include dir and the library. One thing that can happen is there's no binary for your compiler, so you will have to build `curl` from sources first.

Comment: I get an error curlbuild.h not found, but that file does not exist on my system. I get past the main curl parts missing though.  http://i.imgur.com/fpdHaXG.png

Comment: ./buildconf solved that.

Comment: So, how is it going? I built `cURL` from source with the CMake gui and did the same for `curlcpp`. Now I have a `libcurlcpp.a` in `<whatever_path_you_have_curlcpp>/build/src`

Comment: Never got the issue fixed. went with qnetworkaccessmanager instead

Answer (score 0):

Install this:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev 

apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```